# Can I build an abstract visitor using a typelist?

Tags: c++, boost

So I have an abstract class that is the base of any visitor that using a collection of objects:

```cpp
class visitor
{
  virtual void visit(foo) = 0;
  virtual void visit(bar) = 0;
  virtual void visit(baz) = 0;
  virtual void visit(quux) = 0;
};
```

But I also have all of these types saved in a `boost::mpl::list`:

```cpp
using type_list = boost::mpl::list<
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  quux
>;
```

It seems like a shame to have to update the visitor class whenever I add a new type... is there any way I can generate the visitor class automatically by passing it the `type_list`?

`std::enable_if` and `boost::mpl::find` seems to be the way to go, but I can't template virtual methods can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't variadic template virtual methods, but you can template base classes:

```
template<class T> class singleVisitorBase { virtual void visit(T) = 0; };

template<class list> class visitor;
template<class... Ts> class visitor<boost::mpl::list<Ts...>>
    : singleVisitorBase<Ts>... {};
```

Another approach is to use recursive inheritance:

```
template<class list> class visitor;
template<> class visitor<boost::mpl::list<>> {};
template<class T, class... Ts> class visitor<boost::mpl::list<T, Ts...>>
    : singleVisitorBase<T>, visitor<boost::mpl::list<Ts...>> {};
```

However, I prefer single-level multiple inheritance as it produces cleaner type hierarchies that are easier to inspect in a debugger.

In either of these cases there is some space overhead as `visitor` will contain `n` vtable pointers into its vtable, to allow for cast-to-base-type. An alternative with less space overhead but significant compile time overhead is to use Boost.Preprocessor to generate an `n`-length class body via `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`:

```
template<class list, std::size_t N> class visitorImpl;
#define VISITOR_MAX 32
#define VISITOR_VISIT(z,I,_) \
    virtual void visit(typename boost::mpl::at<list, I>::type) = 0;
#define VISITOR_CLASS(z,N,_) \
template<class list>         \
class visitorImpl<list, N>   \
{                            \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(N, VISITOR_VISIT, ) \
};
BOOST_PP_REPEAT(VISITOR_MAX, VISITOR_CLASS, )
template<class list> using visitor
    = visitorImpl<list, typename boost::mpl::size<list>::type::value>;
```

Comment: is the performance penalty of inheritance a linear or constant thing? like the idea of a class having 20+ parents is a bit scary

Comment: @SamKellett in typical implementations it should be constant, although there will be some space overhead (20+ vtable pointers into the same vtable); see http://tinydrblog.appspot.com/?p=89001